# TypeError: this.$set is not a function

Tags: vue.js

Hi I am geting this error:
**Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: this.$set is not a function**

And here is the code:

```
     export default {
        data: function() {
            return { movies: '' }
        },

        ready: function() {
            this.showMovies()
        },

        methods: {
            showMovies: function() {
                 this.$http.get(config.api.url + '/movies').then(function (response) {
                    this.$set('movies', response.data)
                 })
             }
        }
     }
```

Comment: Solved by: `this.$http.get(config.api.url + '/movies/geners', function(geners) {
                    this.$set('geners', geners)
                 })`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The reason why `this.$set` is not a function in your example code is because `this` doesn't refer to Vue ViewModel instance anymore.

To make code you've posted working, you need to keep reference to it:

```
export default {
    data: function() {
        return { movies: '' }
    },

    ready: function() {
        this.showMovies()
    },

    methods: {
        showMovies: function() {
             var vm = this; // Keep reference to viewmodel object
             this.$http.get(config.api.url + '/movies').then(function (response) {
                vm.$set('movies', response.data)
             })
         }
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

in the callback function you're loosing the Vue instance (`this`), this could be solved by using the arrow function `()=>{...}` :

```
   this.$http.get(config.api.url + '/movies').then((response)=> {
                    this.$set('movies', response.data)
                 })
```

or binding the callback to `this` :

```
   this.$http.get(config.api.url + '/movies').then(function (response) {
                    this.$set('movies', response.data)
                 }).bind(this)
```