# Attach correct data format to draw a chart

Tags: arrays, vue.js, object, chart.js, chartkick

I'm new to Vuejs, vue-Chartkick, and Chartjs. I was trying to insert the restructured data into an object to draw a multiple-series chart. But it did not work.

```
<template>
    <line-chart :data="data"></line-chart>
</template>

<script>
import axios from "axios";
export default {
    name: 'SummaryGraph',
    data () {
        return {
            data: [
              {name: 'A', data: {}},
              {name: 'B', data: {}}
            ]
        }
    },
    created() {
        let apiURL_1 = axios.get('http://localhost:3000/MyfirstData');
        let apiURL_2 = axios.get('http://localhost:3000/MysecondData');

        axios.all([apiURL_1, apiURL_2]).then(axios.spread((first_response, second_response) => {
            this.data[0]['data'] = first_response.data.reduce(function(result, current) {return Object.assign(result, current);}, {});
            this.data[1]['data'] = second_response.data.reduce(function(result, current) {return Object.assign(result, current);}, {});
        })).catch(error => {
            console.log(error)
        });
    }
}
</script>
```

**The 1st original returned data:**

```
[{"A":6},{"B":6},{"C":4}]
```

**The 2nd original returned data:**

```
[{"A":1},{"B":2},{"C":2}]
```

The 1st data after restructured by using reduce method.

```
{"A": 6,"B": 6,"C": 4}
```

The 2nd data after restructured by using reduce method.

```
{"A": 1,"B": 2,"C": 2}
```

If I directly insert the 1st and 2nd restructured data into the Vue instance
Like this:

```
<script>
export default {
    name: 'SummaryGraph',
    data () {
        return {
            data: [
              {name: 'A', data: {"A": 6,"B": 6,"C": 4}},
              {name: 'B', data: {"A": 1,"B": 2,"C": 2}}
            ]
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

It worked. The graph showed up. I don't know why.

Comment: Have you tried `this.$set(this.data[0], 'data', first_response.data.reduce....... )` ? https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#For-Objects

Comment: It raised an error about something wrong from `this.$set` when I write like this `this.$set(this.data[0], 'data', first_response.data.reduce(function(result, current) {return Object.assign(result, current);}, {})` **under** axios.all........

Comment: Try storing the value of `first_response.data.reduce` in a temp var and then assigning it using `this.$set`

Comment: `var value1 = ''; var value2 = '';    value1 = first_response.data.reduce(function(result, current) {return Object.assign(result, current);}, {});     value2 = second_response.data.reduce(function(result, current) {return Object.assign(result, current);}, {});   this.$set(this.data[0], 'data', value1);   this.$set(this.data[1], 'data', value2);` . I tried to console.log(data). The error is `TypeError: _this.$set is not a function`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34660814/909973 `this` refers to the wrong thing in your axios callback. Store a reference to `this` to use in your callback like this example.

Comment: `var vm = this;
        axios.all([apiURL_1, apiURL_2]).then(axios.spread((first_response, second_response) => {
            vm.$set(data[0], 'data', first_response.data.reduce(function(result, current) {return Object.assign(result, current);}, {});)
            vm.$set(data[1], 'data', second_response.data.reduce(function(result, current) {return Object.assign(result, current);}, {});)`  Does not work at all. I'm not sure I followed the provided source correctly.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239063/discussion-between-bassxzero-and-cristian).